# How get query result as an array in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
const answer = req.body.answer;
const questionId = req.body.questionId;

const e =  sequelize.query('SELECT answer FROM questionbanks WHERE id = questionId ');
console.log(e);
```

Comment: sequelize.query is promise method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
sequelize.query(`SELECT answer FROM questionbanks WHERE id = ${questionId} ).then(records => console.log(records));
```